# Xaml parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms, xaml

Boas, eu tenho um problema que não consigo resolver, quando vou uma preview do que fiz em "XAML", deparo-me sempre com este erro.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: TeamDetailsPage é uma classe que você criou?

Comment: @LINQ sim essa é a minha page

Comment: Já tentou criar um construtor sem parâmetros nela?

Comment: Não , mas penso que isso não interfere em nada